# Node JS live result from MySQL

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js

I'm trying to show the results from my DB in table. I want the users to see every change made in the table(insert, update or delete) live without refreshing the page.

My first question is how to fetch my DB data in table like this. I also would like actions taken by the users to be lively visible from other users(like edit, delete, create).

[image]

This is my server.js

```
    var io=require('socket.io'), mysql=require('mysql');
    var express = require('express');
    var connection = mysql.createConnection({
       host     : 'localhost',
       user     : 'root',
       password : '',
       database : 'lolast'
   });

   connection.connect(function(err) {
      if(err) {
          console.log('error when connecting to db:', err);
          setTimeout(handleDisconnect, 2000);
      } 
  });

 var ws=io.listen(3000);
 var socketCount = 0
 ws.on('connection', function(socket) {
     socketCount++

     // Let all sockets know how many are connected
    ws.emit('users connected', socketCount);

    socket.on('disconnect', function() {
       // Decrease the socket count on a disconnect, emit
        socketCount--
        ws.emit('users connected', socketCount)
     });
 });
```

And this is my client side:

```
    <script  src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://127.0.0.1:3000/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
       // Connect to our node/websockets server
       var socket = io.connect('http://localhost:3000');

       // New socket connected, display new count on page
       socket.on('users connected', function(data){
          $('#usersConnected').html('Users connected: ' + data)
       })

    })
   </script>
   <div id="usersConnected"></div>
```

My user counter is working fine, show the result in live but I having trouble with my sql data.

I will be very greatfull if someone helps me.

Comment: MySQL does not "notify" other clients when data are changed. For that you either have to do some polling and have means to decide what changed (some kindof a `last_updated` column maybe) or create some event system directly in your app, where client which updates the db will fire an event to tell others to reload something.

Comment: This is a pretty hard problem and MySQL doesn't exactly have out-of-the-box support for this. I think Firebase specializes in this? Mongo might be better off and there's probably other middleware solutions. The roll-your-own solution is to do manual polling like jkavalik is suggested. This is a nightmare to scale and you won't get very far without serious MySQL chops.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is replication logs or bin-logs on mysql. Have a look at this repo: https://github.com/numtel/mysql-live-select

Answer (score 1):

This is an incomplete answer but can at least get you started on the problem -

- MySQL doesn't have any sort of out-of-the-box support for this. Whatever you do will need to be based on polling, which is not impossible to scale, but requires very smart use of MySQL to scale well.
- There are better storage products for this. I think Firebase specializes in this (bought by Google?) and I'm positive there is an AWS-product that does this.
- Even NoSQLs like Redis have push support. I think MongoDB does.
- There are probably other middleware solutions. There might be frameworks that will create and maintain the tables themselves. Try searching for language-agnostic frameworks or frameworks in other languages and see if anything points you in the right direction.
- The roll-your-own solution will look something like this: all of your queries that should be visible to other users will need to go into tables, or be kept track of in tables, with timestamps, that your clients can query for anything since they last received data. This is *hard* to scale without serious MySQL chops (but reasonable to scale if you know MySQL well). (Just making these claims from my experience at a MySQL startup).

Answer (score -1):

I am using firebase for getting live events for changing value in database.
For view perspective I have hooked firebase with Bootstrap's DataTable.
You can check small use of it over here. Firebase is one of the best solution for this.
https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/libraries/angular/guide/synchronized-arrays.html